# Efficient top eigenvalue computation for Hessian of neural networks

Tags: neural-networks

I train a neural network - one of the Resnet variations ($\approx 10^7$ parameters) on the CIFAR-10 dataset - and after each epoch, I would like to find the smallest/largest eigenvalues of its Hessian. Formally, we can view our NN as a function: let our dataset (training set) be $D$, let $x$ be NN parameters, and we want to minimize

$$f(x) = \frac 1 {|D|} \sum_{d \in D} \text{loss}(x, d)$$

Now, we consider Hessian of this function
$$\nabla^2 f(x) = \frac 1 {|D|} \sum_{d \in D} \nabla^2 \text{loss}_{xx}(x, d)$$

For a given NN parameters $x$, I want to find the smallest and largest eigenvalues $\nabla^2 f(x)$.
For that, I can use hessian-vector products, i.e. for any vector $v$ I can compute $\nabla^2 f(x) \cdot v$ (PyTorch has a [built-in mechanism](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#torch.autograd.grad) to compute $\nabla^2 \text{loss}_{xx}(x, d) \cdot v$ for any batch $d$), so, for example, I can use the power method. However, the pure power method will be very slow: one needs a pass over the entire data $D$ to compute the true Hessian-vector product.

**Question**: do you know of an efficient algorithm for this task? To be precise, I mean that both eigenvalues can be computed with a reasonable multiplicative error within at most 1 minute each. (The run aside from that takes 5 hours and I need to compute both eigenvalues about $40$ times per run, so it's the time I'm ready to spare. There are a lot of runs, so this is my limit.)

Note that I'm asking about an algorithm that you **know to be efficient** for this (or similar) problem. I tried the power method, accelerated power method, stochastic power method, Oja's algorithm, gradient-based algorithm, its accelerated version, algorithms from https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02670. All these experiments take a lot of time and so far I didn't have any success, no matter how much engineering I used. When eigenvalues are close to $0$ (e.g. of order $-\frac 12$, when the largest eigenvalue is of order $100$), either convergence takes a lot of time or the results are unstable/unreliable.
Just in case, I'm aware of [PyHessian](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.07145) (and the first version of my code is based on theirs).

My **current best solution** is the one that performs the power method with increasing batch size. In a good scenario, it looks like this:
[image]
[image]
[image]
The left plot shows eigenvalues, the right plot shows what I call "error": $\|v - \frac {H v} {v^\top H v}\|$, where $Hv$ is a hessian-vector product computed at the last iteration, and $v$ is the current eigenvector candidate of norm $1$.
Red lines separate cases when I dramatically increase batch size: I first use a lot of iterations with a small batch size (64 images), then 1000 images per batch, and in the end, I increase the batch size until it reaches the whole dataset. It can be seen that the power method with a smaller batch size always has a limit beyond which it can't grow.

The problem is that this approach takes $4$ minutes for one eigenvalue - $4$ times more than what I'm ready to spare. Decreasing the number of batches at every step is detrimental to quality when eigenvalues are small. If the eigenvalue is closer to $0$, it already doesn't finish converging to it with this number of iterations:
[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I understand you're only looking for things we know will work, not ideas for something to try, so this isn't what you're looking for, but: have you tried a SGD version of power iteration?  (i.e., GD : SGD as power iteration : it)  In other words, in each iteration you pick a batch $B$ that is a randomly chosen subset of the training set, compute $1/|B| \sum_{d \in B} \nabla^2 \text{loss}_xx(x,d) \cdot v$, and use that as an estimate of $\nabla^2 f(x) \cdot v$ in your power iteration.  Does that do anything useful?  I apologize if this is not helpful.

Comment: @D.W., I've edited my post to show my best solution. It includes what you suggest. I've also noticed that I specified the wrong computation time: it should be 2 minutes for both eigenvalues instead of 10.